# How to get all user information from auth user in django rest framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework, jwt

I am using Django sample JWT and I already set up for the login user. let say now I have a login user token. but at the client-side, we still need to show like user name, user image, and email address. How to get this information in the client-side?

I created a new method that will return current login user at backend=>

```
#get token for login user
    @action(detail=False, methods=['get'])
    def get_current_user(self,request):

        data = {}

        data["username"] = request.user.username
        .
        .
        .

        return Response({format(data)})
```

It's the correct way? or Can I serialize `request.user` and return directly? Is there any serializer for  Auth-User? I am stuck there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going for a basic retrieve of the user,you should create a serializer for the user and a generic view which uses that serializer to return the data